# script to add and remove auto-increment property from a column

Tags: sql-server, identity-insert

For a sql script I'm working on, I need to programmatically remove the identity, identity seed, and identity increment for a column in an existing table, then add them back to the table at the end of the script.  Does anyone have a reference or an example on how to do this?

Comment: Are you asking this because you need to insert some specific values into an identity column?

Comment: Yes, ported in from another database over a linked server.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should do this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <TableName> ON
-- Do the inserting in the table with name <TableName>
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <TableName> OFF
```

For more details look in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql).

Comment: But where we added `column_name` on which we want to set `identity` ? @Ivan Ferić

Comment: You don't need to specify any column name - this will enable identity insert on the table

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you just do this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE] ON
```

And then back on:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE] OFF
```

This will allow you to enter manual data in the identity column.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Comment: You should first set it to ON, and in the end to OFF. With ON it signalizes that you are about to do manual inserts on identity column.

Comment: Thanks, a little Friday morning aixelsyd. :)

Comment: You still have it the other way around.